# How can you add a bread crumb in a Crystal Xcelsius Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I add a bread crumb in a Crystal Xcelsius Report? I need to track the navigation of my clicks on my charts.

Comment: Are you navigating from one dashboard to another or are you trying to track clicks within a single Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The crew over at [BDI Systems](http://www.bdisys.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=80) have a free breadcrumb add on that should do what you're looking for, in theory. I say this because in my brief time playing with it I was not able to figure it out and documentation is nearly non-existent.

Another possibility to making a breadcrumb type is by implementing the native filter component as the basis for your visual hierarchy.

The third possible option would be creating a state machine pattern within excel using lists derived from conditional logic present on the dashboard at any one time.

The final route would be to develop your own component using Xcelsius's flex 2 sdk.

Let know if you want to drill into one of the 4 solutions posted above further so we can get you where you want to be.